# WPF- How to apply Style to Multiple controls within a Panel

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, stackpanel

I need to apply style to different controls within  a Stack Panel. They are all of different type i.e. TreeView,Listview,ComboBox etc.
Is there a way I can apply a style at StackPanel level to be applicable for these controls.
I don't want to apply style individually to these controls.
Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks..

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this by declaring the Styles withing the StackPanel Resources. You have to declare each Style without a key for them to be automatically applied to every target control within the StackPanel.

```xml
<StackPanel>
     <StackPanel.Resources>
      <!-- Styles declared here will be scoped to the content of the stackpanel  -->

      <!-- This is the example of style declared without a key, it will be applied to every TreeView. Of course you'll have to add Setters etc -->
      <Style TargetType="TreeView">
      </Style>
     </StackPanel.Resources>

     <!-- Content -->

     <!-- This treeview will have the style declared within the StackPanel Resources applied to it-->
     <TreeView />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: In some questions depending on the tag you might want to apply syntax highlighting manually, see the code of my edit or the *"Stack Exchange additions"* section in the [editing-help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

As Jean-Louis says, you can specify a `Style` within the `StackPanel` resource dictionary and it will only be applied to matching elements within that `StackPanel`.

In order to have a single `Style` match all of your controls, you will need to specify it with a `TargetType` of a common base class for all of those controls, such as `Control`

```
<StackPanel>
  <StackPanel.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Control">
      <!-- Setters etc here -->
    </Style>
  </StackPanel.Resources>

<!-- Controls here -->

</StackPanel>
```